# Zend framework 2 method routing

Tags: php, frameworks, routes, zend-framework2

I would like to separate a form display and processing in the router config in Zend Framework 2 (v2.3.1):

```
        'login' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/login',
            ),
            'child_routes' => array(

                'show' => array(
                    'type' => 'method',
                    'options' => array(
                        'verb' => 'get',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Main',
                            'action' => 'loginShow'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),

                'process' => array(
                    'type' => 'method',
                    'options' => array(
                        'verb' => 'post',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Main',
                            'action' => 'loginProcess'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),

            ),
        ),
```

Somehow this doesn't work, i get the following error message:

Part route may not terminate

It would be great to use the same URL (route) but two different actions (depending on the request method) for displaying and processing the login form.

Thank you very much for your help!

M

Answer (score 1):

You need to add may_terminate = true and that should solve your problems.

```
     'login' => array(
        'type' => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/login',
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(

            'show' => array(
                'type' => 'method',
                'options' => array(
                    'verb' => 'get',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Main',
                        'action' => 'loginShow'
                    ),
                ),
            ),

            'process' => array(
                'type' => 'method',
                'options' => array(
                    'verb' => 'post',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Main',
                        'action' => 'loginProcess'
                    ),
                ),
            ),

        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Unfortunately it wont help :(

Adding may_termiante results the following error:

Controller:
    not-found(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: not-found)

I think it's because in the parent route there is no controller and action defined. And i can't define them there, because the default controller should depend on method type (= child route).

Comment: Have you added your controller to the invokables file in module.config.php?

To clarify, it should be something like :

     'controllers' => [
        'invokables' => [
            'Main' => 'Path\To\Controller',
         ],
     ],

Comment: Thank you for your anwer, yes, i added it. Can't figure out what the problem is... :(